# developing on my computer localhost and moving to ec2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

If you are developing website but testing on localhost,
what if you copy paste entire src into the ec2 instance and run it from there? Would that be creating a localhost inside ec2?
Should I be developing in a way that I will not be using localhost on ec2? because ec2 itself is going to be a host? I feel like I'm kinda confused on concepts here.

Thanks

I was developing on local and then created ec2 and was testing what I developed and that hit me - It seemed a bit weird to run 'localhost' from ec2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "testing on localhost", do you just mean that's what you type in your browser address bar?

The name `localhost` is relative and just refers to the machine the code is running on. So if your code running on an EC2 instance uses `localhost`, it would be connecting to itself, same as if it was running on your own machine.

Hardcoding *any* hostname in your code is probably a bad idea. Instead, consider using something like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to configure these. This way, you can have one `.env` file on your own machine and another on your host.

Comment: ah yes. I meant what you type in browser address bar. If you are developing on your own computer, it would be http://localhost:1234//.  Of course, I would not use localhost as a domain - my question was about running 'localhost' on an active ec2 instance. But I think your explanation that localhost is relative and just refers to the machine answers my question. Thank you!